# Guadar numeros de una Texbox en un Vector(array)

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente duda: ¿Cómo podría guardar lo que está en un texbox con números separados unos de otros por comas, los cuales son introducidos por el usuario en un array(vector)? El número máximo de números que se puede introducir es 3, y se separan por comas, ya que necesito hacer un producto cruzado de vectores (Producto punto). De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar el `Split()` para separar por la coma

```
string[] lista = TextBox1.Text.Split(',');
```

asi obtendrias el array con cada valor ingresado

Si necesitas que sea un array numerico cambia un poco

```
int[] lista = TextBox1.Text.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

pero hay varias formas de conseguir lo mismo

[Split string, convert ToList() in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911717/split-string-convert-tolistint-in-one-line)

Comment: Me carca un error en la Instrucion: "int[] lista = TextBox1.Text.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();", exactamente en .Select

Comment: el Select() es de linq, necesitas tener el: using System.Linq;