# Problema de arrays con datos provenientes de un TextBox

Tags: c#

El inconveniente ocurre cuando trato de desplegar el contenido de mi `array` en un `Label`.

Los datos que intento desplegar del `array`, provienen de un `TextBox`, y son numéricos, ya que básicamente lo que hice fue tratar de que cuando el usuario introduzca números en un `TextBox` *(separados cada uno por comas)*, se cree un `array`, y con `Split`, aislar dichos números y guardarlos en dicho `array`, para luego recorrer cada espacio, y guardar cada valor en una variable y desplegar finalmente en un `Label` dichos valores.

Aparentemente esta bien, pero al correr tengo el siguiente error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

No se que pueda estar mal, así que si alguien puede ayudarme, seria muy útil para mi.

Este es mi código:

```
int[] A = txtVA.Text.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
int[] B = txtVB.Text.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
string cadena=" ";

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cadena = Convert.ToString(A[i]);
    cadena += cadena;

}
lblre.Text = cadena;
```

Comment: ¿En que línea muestra el error? Cuando debugueas, ¿se separan y cargan correctamente los arrays A y B?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Guadar numeros de una Texbox en un Vector(array)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226102/guadar-numeros-de-una-texbox-en-un-vectorarray)

Answer (score 1):

Código completo:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtVA.Text))
    return;

string cadena = string.Empty;
try
{
    int[] A = txtVA.Text.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    cadena = string.Join(" ", A);
}
catch { }

lblre.Text = cadena;
lblre.Refresh();
```

Prueba esta versión.

Comment: Amigo, ise la siguiente correcion, pero nada

Comment: Donde va el if?

Comment: Podrias editarlo en el codigo?

Comment: Amigo, me sigue saliendo el mismo error :c

Comment: No funciona, pruebo con : 1,2,3 pero no realiza nada

Comment: Haora simplemente no hace nada

Comment: Si alguno de de los 2 textboxs estan vacios entra al `if` y terminar la ejecución del método

Comment: Eres lo maximo, si funciona n.n

Comment: @AxwellDuarte si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema, por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.